# A detail in the proof of the uniqueness in convergence, (r-mean)

Tags: probability

Iam reading a proof about the uniqueness in convergence , for random variables. Particularly convergence in r-mean.

So i have come to a detail which i don't understand , here goes:

$E \lvert X-Y\rvert^r = 0 $ ,  yields $\enspace P(\lvert X - Y \rvert = 0) = 1$

the question is how $E \lvert X-Y\rvert^r = 0 $ ,yields $\enspace P(\lvert X - Y \rvert = 0) = 1$

$X,Y$ are random variables

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z=|X-Y|^r$. Apply [Markov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality) to $Z$, with any $\epsilon >0$:

$$P(Z\ge\epsilon) \le \frac{E(Z)}{\epsilon}=0$$
But $P(Z\ge\epsilon)=P(|X-Y|\ge \epsilon^{1/r})$. Hence $P(|X-Y| \ne 0) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the discrete case:

put $Z = X-Y$

$E[X-Y]^r = \sum\limits_{ z } \lvert z \rvert^r p_Z(z)= 0$ . Since $\lvert z \rvert^r > 0$ (except for $z = 0$) , we must have that $P_Z (\lvert X-Y\rvert = 0) =1$

Maybe someone can  show it in the continuous case?

Answer (score 0):

If $P(|X-Y|\ne0)\ne0$ then $P(|X-Y|\geqslant\varepsilon)\geqslant\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon$ positive and small enough hence $E(|X-Y|^r)\geqslant E(|X-Y|^r;|X-Y|\geqslant\varepsilon)\geqslant\varepsilon^r\geqslant\varepsilon^{r+1}$, in particular $E(|X-Y|^r)\ne0$.

Contrapositively, if $E(|X-Y|^r)=0$ then $P(|X-Y|\ne0)=0$ hence $P(|X-Y|=0)=1$